# Sed insert blank line below search string then insert string on the next line

Tags: bash, sed

I have a sed expression in a function that I pass parameters to.

```
insert_after_new_line() {
    if ! grep -q "${2}" "${3}"; then
        sed -i "/${1}/{N;N;a ${2}}" "${3}"
    fi
}

insert_after_new_line search insert textfile.txt
```

I am trying to have a blank line inserted below the search string and the insert string inserted after.

so

```
text
text
search
text
```

becomes

```
text
text
search

insert
text
```

but I keep getting the error

> sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'

Comment: For braced expressions with commands such as `a,c,i,r,R,w,W and the substitution command with a w flag` use two or more `-e` options or write a script and separate them by a newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this. works in command line

```
sed -i  '/search/a \\ninsert' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` really delimiters commands by a newline. There is a `;` but it does not work for all commands, mostly these which take file name as an argument. `;` does not work for `r` `R` or for example `a`. Sed will read everything after `a` command, so sed interprets is like `a ${2}}` as a single command, in result it does not find enclosing `}`, cause it's been eaten by `a` command. You need a newline:

```
sed -i "/${1}/{N;N;a ${2}
}" "${3}"
```

or

```
sed -i "/${1}/{N;N;a ${2}"$'\n'"}" "${3}"
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
sed -i '/search/{G;ainsert 
}' file
```

You can replace the text by shell variable, but replace the single quotes by double quotes too.

Comment: If you want this all on one line, you might try: `sed -i '/search/G;//a insert' file`